# Netbeans 8.2 project cant run over glassfish or tomcat server

Tags: javascript, java, json, tomcat, glassfish

I need to know why my application cant run over netbeans / glassfish server, I think I need to convert my application to run over glassfish instead of tomcat by adding some classes and remove some others.

Below figure show the glassfish output and error through browser

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, edit your question and add some debugging details, e.g. the code of the `DatabaseConnection#getResultFromSqlQuery` method that is causing the NPE. Add it as **text** not an image, since the latter is not searchable (see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.